# How can I do an overlapping scatter using Boost.MPI?

Tags: boost, mpi, boost-mpi

I want to distribute a vector with overlapping elements. For example, if I had [1,2,3], I'd want [1,2] to get sent to one node, and [2,3] to get sent to another. I'm familiar with how to do this using MPI, but how would I do this using Boost::MPI?

Answer (score 0):

Never tried, but I think you can use [ranges or slices](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/vector_proxy.htm). You may need to provide your own serialization if it's not included in Boost Serialization.